# Django installation - virtualenv.py errors out

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to create a Virtual Environment for my django site. 
Command is below. but it says "You must provide a DEST_DIR" though I have given the directory name "SOWL".

virtualenv.py SOWL --no-site-packages

http://screencast.com/t/rej893zrg

I have spent half a day on this. I can't find anything on google search either.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
SHM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance your command is out of order; the flags come first, directory last. However it doesn't seem to matter; the command, as you ran it, works for me on Mac and Windows.

I'd guess the problem lies with your installation of virtualenv. Virtualenv is also one of those tools that never seems to get updated. Make sure you have the latest. Install with `pip` (first choice) or if you need the actual `virtualenv.py` file, either way the instructions are [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/).

**UPDATE** Here's an install-Python-in-Windows guide. I know you already have Python, but this will make sure your PATH is setup and get you PIP and Virtualenv as well.

1. Install [Python](http://www.python.org/download/) using the Windows installer
2. [Add](http://pythoncentral.org/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-windows-7-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) this to your PATH environment variable: `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\`
3. Get [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) by downloading the `distribute_setup.py` file. (There is no Windows installer; the script does it all.)
4. Get [PIP](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) by downloading the `get-pip.py` file.
5. `python distribute_setup.py`
6. `python get-pip.py`
7. `pip install virtualenv`

Now you are set with **virtualenv**. However there's more — the [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) makes life easy. It's only for bash shells, but there's a Windows port [here](https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win). There are installation instructions, tips and a rundown of the nifty new commands that the wrapper gives you.

1. `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`
2. `pyassoc`
3. Create a new environment variable: `WORKON_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\Envs`

Now you can do this to create your virtualenv (and notice the prompt change to indicate which env you are in):

```
mkvirtualenv --distribute SOWL
>>>(SOWL) C:\Users\User>
```

Comment: In installed PIP (get-pip.py) using the the blog mentioned above. Installed successfully. But when I get to the next section to run "pip install virtualenv", I am getting the following error. How do I get past this?

Comment: You didn't paste the error message. I'm guessing it had to do with not having Distribute. Anyway, I updated the answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. yes. I didn't have distribute at all. it was not in the blog. I will check what you have mentioned here and reach back to you if need more help. Again, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I removed Django and did all these step by step. And I am getting this.
 C:\SHM\Personal\SuccessOwl\SOWL0.1>mkvirtualenv SOWL
 The system cannot find the path specified.
 The system cannot find the path specified.
 The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: I tried "where python.exe"
I get the right path: C:\Python27\python.exe
Only one result. Not sure what is wrong here. I am only trying to get Django up and running. I don't even need a virtual environment. just ONE site running. This is really painful.

Comment: I removed everything installed it without virtual environment and it worked fine. But thanks a lot for informing me on the Windows Installation path. Though it didn't solve my particular problem, it is very useful information. I am marking this as the right answer. Thanks again,

Comment: Glad you finally got it. Virtualenv definitely works best on a clean setup. I can see where stuff previously installed into the base python environment would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think your parameters are just out of order. Did you try

virtualenv.py --no-site-packages SOWL

Comment: I tried that and I get the same message - "You must provide a DEST_DIR"